# Solving homogeneous systems using Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a system of equations:

$$2x_1 + 6x_2 - 4x_3 = 0$$
$$3x_1 +  x_2 + 7x_3 = 0$$
$$4x_1 -  x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$$

I have tried to solve it, but I'm stuck at this part:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&3&-2&0\\3&1&7&0\\4&-1&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what Gaussian elimination means? You want to get only $0$s under the leading $1$s. You have three types of elementary row operations to work with. Use the row operations to try eliminate any numbers under the main diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Now you want to subtract 3 times the first row from the second one, and 4 times the first from the third one.

Comment: after that, do i multiply the second row by 1/8? what do i do to the third row?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Once you get a 1 in the 2,2 position you subtract from the third row in order to get a 0 in the 3,2 position.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make $0$ the first element of the $2$ last rows (by  performing $\text{row}_2=\text{row}_2-3\times\text{row}_1$  and $\text{row}_3=\text{row}_3-4\times\text{row}_1$).

Now you need to make $0$ the second element of the third row doing just the same than before. If im not wrong $\text{row}_2=(0,-8,13)$ and $\text{row}_3=(0,-13,10)$, so you do: 
$$\text{row}_3=\frac{8}{13}\times\text{row}_3-\text{row}_2=\left(0,0,-\frac{89}{13}\right)$$

The numbers maybe are wrong because I didn't use a calculator.